# What SQL Error codes should be allowed to retry?

Tags: c#, error-handling, sql-server-2014, high-availability

We have a SQL Server 2014 AlwaysOn Availability Group that we connect to via standard C# `SqlConnection` objects. We want to catch the exceptions that are happening when a failover is triggered either manually or automatically and retry the command after a period of waiting.

We don't just want to retry every command that fails, just the transactions that failed because of a failover.

Does Microsoft produce a list (or is there a list somewhere) of error codes that we can check for?

Answer (score 3):

Microsoft has build a Transient Error Detection Strategy for Azure once to use in the Transient Fault Handling Application Block.

> The Transient Fault Handling Application Block (Topaz) makes your application more robust by providing the logic for handling transient faults. It does this in two ways.
>
> First, the block includes logic to identify transient faults for a number of common cloud-based services in the form of detection strategies. These detection strategies contain built-in knowledge that is capable of identifying whether a particular exception is likely to be caused by a transient fault condition.

They have identified sql error codes that indicate a transient failure. While it is aimed for the cloud (for Azure Sql Server) we have successfully used it in our own on-premises environment.

You can take a look at their code and extract the sql codes you can check for:

https://github.com/Dixin/EnterpriseLibrary.TransientFaultHandling.Core/blob/master/Source/TransientFaultHandling.Data.Core/SqlDatabaseTransientErrorDetectionStrategy.cs

Comment: Very very valuable info! The link seems to be stale but googling 'SqlDatabaseTransientErrorDetectionStrategy.cs' gets you the information!

Comment: @HansLindgren thanks, I've updated the answer with a working link.

Answer (score 1):

It's for ms sql 2000, but probably the "error levels" are the same. I hope, it will help you

http://www.developer.com/tech/article.php/724711/Microsoft-SQL-Server-2000-Error-Messages.htm

**EDIT:**

Here's the documentation about error levels in msdn: (sql2014)
https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms164086(v=sql.120).aspx